# Reusable typed react-apollo component with query

Tags: typescript, react-apollo

It is possible to create a typed `<Query>` `<Mutation>` or `<Subscription>` [by extending the respective class](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing.html):

```
class MyQuery extends Query<TData, TVariables> { }
```

However, in this case I would have to supply the `query` every time I use `<MyQuery>`:

```
<MyQuery query={queries.MyQuery}> // etc.
```

Is there a nice way to "bake in" the query, so that `<MyQuery>` can be reused without having to supply `query={...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you can use a little wrapper component:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
function cannedQuery<TData, TVariables>(query: DocumentNode) {
  return (props: Omit<QueryProps<TData, TVariables>, "query">) =>
    <Query query={query} {...props}/>;
}

const MyQuery = cannedQuery<TData, TVariables>(gql`...`);
```

I'm not familiar with `react-apollo`, so if this doesn't work, let me know what goes wrong and I may be able to come up with something else.  It seems to me that everyone using `react-apollo` with TypeScript would want this, so you could propose adding this helper to `react-apollo`.